# How to use a table and borders to create signature lines

Tags: html, css

Im creating a PDF document, where you would be able to fill in your name, cell phone number and signature.

Ive tried numerous ways to create this, this is the current attempt, but as you can so the margins are being thrown off completely, so its very important that the table/border-lines resizes with the screen width.

So would i need to use a media query to solve my problem?

I dont know what else to use for this to work, do you have any suggestions?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em
}

tr,
td {
  width: 350px;
  height: 40px;
  font: 12px arial;
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: black
}

.field1 {
  /*        background-color: #119494;*/
  /*        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;*/
  width: 100px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: -10%
}

.field {
  /*        background-color: #119494;*/
  /*        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;*/
  width: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.details {
  background-color: cream;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  /*        background-color: lightgrey;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 50%
  /*        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;*/
}

.details1 {
  background-color: cream;
  width: 700px;
  /*        background-color: lightgrey;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  /*        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;*/
}
```

```html
<table>

  <!--            <hr width="99%" size="4" color=#6C5B7B>   -->
  <tr>
    <td class="field1"><strong>FULL NAME</strong></td>
    <td class="details1"></td>

  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td class="details"></td>
    <td class="field"><strong>SIGNATURE</strong></td>
    <td class="details"></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="field"><strong> CELL</strong></td>
    <td class="details3"></td>
    <td class="field"><strong>CAR REGISTRATION</strong></td>
    <td class="details3"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you meant?

```css
      body{
            font-family:sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.5em
            
        }
         tr, td{  
        width: 350px;
        height:40px;
        font: 12px arial;
        font-size:15pt;
            color: black 
        
        
    }
        
    .field1{
/*        background-color: #119494;*/
/*        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;*/
        width:100px;
        color:black;
        font-size:15px;
        margin-left:-10%    
            
       
    }
        
    .field{
/*        background-color: #119494;*/
/*        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;*/
        width:10px;
        color:black;
        font-size:15px;
        
           
            
       
    }
      
    .details{
        background-color:cream;
        /* width:30px; */ /* no need */
         margin-left:5%;
/*        background-color: lightgrey;*/
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        margin-left:50%
/*        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;*/
        

    }
             
    .details1{
        background-color:cream;
        width:700px; 
        
/*        background-color: lightgrey;*/
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
/*        text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px white;*/
        

    }
```

```html
<table> 
            
<!--            <hr width="99%" size="4" color=#6C5B7B>   -->
            <tr >
                <td class="field1"><strong>FULL NAME</strong></td>
                <td class="details1"></td>
              
            </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
            <tr>   
                <td class="field"><strong>ID</strong></td>
                <td class="details"></td>
                <td class="field"><strong>SIGNATURE</strong></td>
                <td class="details"></td>
                 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td class="field"><strong> CELL</strong></td>
                <td class="details"></td> <!-- changed the classname from details3 to details -->
                <td class="field"><strong>CAR REGISTRATION</strong></td>
                <td class="details"></td> <!-- changed the classname from details3 to details -->
            </tr>
              
            </table>
```

Comment: Hi @Itay thank you for your response, it seems really plain and simple, its not 100% what i wanted, but this will have to do, thank you very much!

Comment: Well tell me how do you want it, and we will improve it together :)

Comment: The only thing is, that its resizing, so this document would be printed out, if i do a print screen view of the html document, it resizes perfectly, but in a normal view, the borders doesnt line up, im not sure why that is, i have attached images of the print view and the normal view.

Comment: Where are your images?